# Http protocol, Content-Length, get page content Python

Tags: python, http-headers

I'm trying to code my own Python 3 http library to learn more about sockets and the Http protocol. My question is, if a do a recv(bytesToRead) using my socket, how can I get only the header and then with the Content-Length information, continue recieving the page content? Isn't that the purpose of the Content-Length header?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past to accomplish this, I will read a portion of the socket data into memory, and then read from that buffer until a "\r\n\r\n" sequence is encountered (you could use a state machine to do this or simply use the string.find() function.  Once you reach that sequence you know all of the headers have been read and you can do some parsing of the headers and then read the entire content length.  You may need to be prepared to read a response that does not include a content-length header since not all responses contain it.

If you run out of buffer before seeing that sequence, simply read more data from the socket into your buffer and continue processing.

I can post a C# example if you would like to look at it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know much about C#, what should I do if I don't find the content-length? Just read until a new line is found?

Comment: That depends on what other headers you have and if the connection is keep-alive.If the connection is close either because you requested it by sending a request header "Connection: close" or because the server does not support keep-alive.  If the connection is close, you just read until there is no more data available on the socket and this represents the end of the document.  Or the server will respond with chunked encoding, in which case you will need to support reading chunked responses.  I have C# examples for this too.  I understand, not knowing C# may make it hard to understand though.

Comment: For a nice example of the state machine, check out ry's [http-parser](https://github.com/ry/http-parser)

Comment: I didn't know about the chunked responses, I'll add that. So I need to make a connection with close to retrieve the data until there's no data available to read? What will change if the conection is sent with Keep-alive?

Comment: For beginners, using connection close will allow you to learn about sockets and http without having to deal with chunked responses that http/1.1 uses.  If you use keep-alive, it will most likely respond with a chunked response, unless it has gzip or some other encoding, in which case a content-length will be sent.  Chunked encoding gives you parts of the response in chunks until nothing is left and then a 0 will be on a line by itself indicating there is no more to be read.  See [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) on wikipedia.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll start with HTTP/1.0 and then include the HTTP/1.1 protocol and the chunked responses. So I need to retrieve the header first and the all the page content or I can just recieve all the data until it ends? because if content-length is not really necessary to recieve the content I could retrieve all the data at once. Do I use multiple recv() or there is a better way to recieve the data?

Comment: To begin with, you could just read the entire response into a buffer, and then separate out the headers from the body by looking for the "\r\n\r\n" sequence.  You should put your recv() calls in a loop in the event that not all data is available yet (i.e. slow server).  Basically you loop as long as recv() returns a non-zero value, recv() will return 0 when there is no more data.  The reason this doesn't work with keep-alive is because without parsing the chunked response as you read it, you don't know if the request is complete, or if there is just no more data available on the socket yet.

Comment: Also, since recv() blocks, if you call it when the server is finished sending data, your program will sit at recv() until the socket terminates because there will be no more data on the socket ever.

Comment: So I have to check if the last character is recieved so I don't make the mistake of doing a recv()  when there's no data right? Or if there's no data, will the recv() return a 0?

Comment: If connection is close, you can just read until recv() returns 0 and then break out of your loop because you know when recv() returns 0 the request is complete and the socket is closed.  If doing keep-alive, then you have to make sure you have received the last character and then break out without calling recv() again because it will sit and block forever.  In keep-alive mode, without parsing, you can't know if recv() returning 0 means the request is completed or if no data is currently available.  With connection close you KNOW that recv returning 0 means you are done.

Comment: I've used the Connection : close header and the recv() in a loop but it keeps looping for ever, I think I should check for the last line.

Comment: Is recv returning 0?  You want to make sure to exit the loop when it returns 0.  I'm [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) if you want to chat.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it checking that the last data recieved was a b''.